# Getting text within element excluding decendants

Tags: jquery

I see that jQuery has the `.text()` function for getting all text within an element and its descendant elements.

Is there a way to only get the text that is directly within the element?

eg.

```
<div>
Here is <b>some</b> text.
</div>
```

From that I would want to get just `Here is  text.`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var result = $('div').contents().map(function() {
    if( this.nodeType === 3 ) {
        return this.data;
    }
}).get().join('');
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PeXue/

This uses the [`contents()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method to get all children of the `div`, including text nodes, then the [`map()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method to build a collection of the text contents of only the text nodes (`this.nodeType === 3`) using their `.data` property.

After that is done, it makes an Array from the collection using the [`get()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method, and finally joins the result using [`.join()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Of course your selector should be specific to the `<div>` you're targeting.

---

**EDIT:** If you want to normalize the spaces between the words a bit, you can trim the leading and trailing white space from the content of each text node using the [`jQuery.trim()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method, then give `.join()` a single space to join each set.

```
var result = $('div').contents().map(function() {
    if( this.nodeType === 3 ) {
        return $.trim( this.data );
    }
}).get().join(' ');

alert( result );
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PeXue/1

We could even shorten it a bit, and ensure that any empty text nodes are excluded at the same time:

```
var result = $('div').contents().map(function() {
    return $.trim( this.data ) || null;
}).get().join(' ');

alert( result );
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PeXue/2

---

**EDIT 2:**

You can get an enormous performance increase by using the [`jQuery.map()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method, which is meant for more generic use.

```
var result = $.map( $('div')[0].childNodes, function(val,i) {
  if (val.nodeType === 3) {
    return val.data;
  }
}).join('');
```

[Here's a performance test](http://jsperf.com/string-from-clone-and-remove-vs-mapping-text-nodes) showing the difference.

Comment: 16 seconds later than your answer.. damn~ LOL

Comment: @Liangliang: Gotta be quick! ;o)

Comment: @patrick dw, Why did you take this approach?  It seems overly complicated by introducing an unnecessary string-parsing concern.  Is the performance better than a DOM approach?

Comment: @smartcaveman: I personally find this simpler than cloning the DOM element, traversing to its children and destroying the child elements. Also leaves room to tidy up the spacing a bit. If I were to guess, I'd say that it is quicker as well, but only performance testing would tell for sure.

Comment: @smartcaveman: Wow, there's a huge difference in Chrome 13. [Here's the performance test.](http://jsperf.com/string-from-clone-and-remove-vs-mapping-text-nodes)

Comment: @smartcaveman: Typically DOM manipulations are fairly heavy. I don't know where most of the weight lies. Could be the clone, could be the remove. Another contributor is the amount of abstraction from the native API with jQuery methods. That always slows things down a bit. A good example of that is where I went from `.contents().map()` to `$.map( div[0].childNodes, ...)`. That alone (well also the ability to remove `.get()`) yielded a tenfold increase. So I suppose that all these factors play a role.

Answer (score 1):

Working example at **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smartcaveman/y6DZp/)**

```
var divClone = $('div').clone();    //  WARNING:
divClone.children().remove();       //  This code is much slower than the 
alert(divClone.text());             //  code in the selected answer.
```

### Update

The performance test in @patrick dw's answer clearly shows that **his approach is the better alternative**.  I did not delete this answer, because I think it is helpful to future readers of the question who might not know which way is better.