# Use of Jquery .not() in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting text within element excluding decendants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487777/getting-text-within-element-excluding-decendants)

I have the following function:

```
function initCBox(){
    CB_Init(); 
    var img1 = $(select.currentImg).attr('src');
    var label = $(select.currentImg).attr('alt');
    var desc = $('.item.active .caption').not($('.description')).text();    

    CB_Open('href=' + img1 + ',,title=' + label + ',,comment=' + desc +'');     
}
```

with the following html:

```
<div class="item" title="Light" href="Light.jpg" >
   <img class="content" alt="Amber Light" src="slides/Light.jpg"/>
<div class="caption">Light
<ul class="icon"> 
      <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="More Info">
          <div class="description ui-icon ui-icon-comment">
          <div class="description_holder"  style="display:none">Amber Light
          <br />Enter Text or HTML Here</div>
          </div> </li> 
    </ul>
</div></div>
```

I want my var = desc to only show the text in the class "caption", not anything in the `<ul class="icon">` ( for simplicity, I only include one `<li>` item but I have others in the `<ul`>). Need help with my excluding all but the caption text. Hope I haven't been too confusing!

Comment: Why don't you put the caption text in a `span` with a class or id?

Comment: Because the javascript I'm using for an image gallery, ContentFlow, uses a div with class caption and my jqueryui icons need to show up within this div ( under the caption) for each image in the gallery.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Felix, seems to have worked for my specific issue.

Comment: Though you don't necessarily want to exclude all descendants (like in the possible duplicate). For example you'd want to include the `<strong>` here: `This <strong>is</strong> my title <ul>...`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a string find and replace:

```
var desc = $('.caption').text(), // The caption and stuff you don't want
    noWant = $('.icon').text();  // Only stuff you don't want
desc = desc.replace(noWant,"");  // Find stuff you don't want and replace w ""
```

The advantage if this way over [excluding descendants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487777/getting-text-within-element-excluding-decendants), is that it will grab the entire text of your description even if includes `<span>`s, `<strong>`s, etc.