# How to selector an element except "div" inside <td>?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting text within element excluding decendants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487777/getting-text-within-element-excluding-decendants)

I'm trying to use `:not` and `.not()` but still not work. I want the result to be only "Monday".

Example markup:

```
 <td id="day_id">
  Monday
   <div class='spec_class'>
    <span>One</span>
    <span>Two</span>
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Btw: Text nodes are not elements. There is no other element besides the `div` inside the table cell.

Comment: @FelixKling: Nice find! (The question this duplicates.)

Comment: Oh, it really do duplicated someone please removed or closed for me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the textNodes of the element

```
var td = jQuery("#day_id");
var textNodes = td.contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    });

console.log(textNodes.text());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ERbWp/)

Comment: He said he wanted "Monday", not "Monday One Two"

Comment: Here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ERbWp/1/) with the question example. Maybe adding a `$.trim(...)` would be nicer.

Comment: I thought this a good solution to solved it. thanks

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Why do you say this won't do what was wanted? The `.contents()` only looks at child nodes, so it's roughly equivalent to the `.childNodes` property. Anything that isn't a text node is being filtered out.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: did you see my updated jsfiddle in the comments above? There is no "One Two" in the console.

Comment: @scessor: I did see it, and *thought* that I saw it outputting "One" and "Two" -- but it clearly doesn't. :-) Thanks.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity: I was looking in the wrong place. If I hadn't already upvoted this, I would now. :-)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery doesn't really "do" text nodes, so this is one of the few places you're better off using raw DOM methods:

```
var text = "",
    node;
for (node = $("#day_id")[0].firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) { // 3 = text node
        text += node.nodeValue;
    }
}
console.log("[" + text + "]"); // "[ Monday ]"
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/epuras) | [source](http://jsbin.com/epuras/edit)

Note the whitespace before and after, because there are text nodes with whitespace before and after the text "Monday". You could use `$.trim()` to get rid of it.

More reading:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)