# jquery selectors - do not select inner elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting text within element excluding decendants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487777/getting-text-within-element-excluding-decendants)

i'm trying to get a part of an element data using 1 selector and only by text() method.
lets say i have the following html code:

```
<div class="price">
     <span class='old_price'>1150</span><br />
     920 
</div>
```

In this case, I only want to get the `920` (without t`1150`). Is it possible to do that using one selector?

For example if I do `div.price.text()`, I will get both prices. So by "one line" I mean `div.price.not("span.old_price").text()` or somthing like that.

Answer (score 0):

from the jQuery API documentation `Description: Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.` so even if you only select the outer element you will get both numbers as part of the result using text();

So what you want is to filter out everything but text nodes

```
$(".price").contents().filter(
    function() {
       return this.nodeType === 3;  // text node
    }
).text();
```

You might want to trim for whitespace (in which case you can wrap the above code with `$.trim()`

Comment: as i said, i need to perform it only with a selector, i cannot use functions etc..

Comment: @ItayD selectors are in essence a function at least to the extend that you can create your own selectors. So I don't see the point of that restriction