# How to fetch the data after the h3 tag

Tags: jquery

I have a div as

```
 <div class="Itm_discrp" style="display:block;">
      <h3>Applle Drink</h3>
      Hai i am very tasty
   </div>
```

I need to fetch the text as "Hai i am very tasty"

I tried as shown below

```
   var item_description = $(this).closest('.lastItm_Wrap').find('.Itm_discrp h3').text().trim();
```

but i am getting `Applle Drink`

could you please let me know how to fetch the text "Hai i am very tasty" instead of "Applle drink" in this case

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/45/

Comment: you want this text on any event ? like click or else?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/11712759/3639582

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a text node so you can get the nextSibling of the h3 element then get its content

```
var item_description = $('.Itm_discrp h3')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue.trim();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0esjv40x/)

Comment: description is optional, and Incase the description is empty , i am getting a error in console , please let me know how to resolve that??

Answer (score 3):

with combination of `.contents().filter()`:

```js
var text = $('.Itm_discrp').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();

alert(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Itm_discrp" style="display:block;">
      <h3>Applle Drink</h3>
      Hai i am very tasty
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yu can try also this jquery code :

```
var item_description = $('.Itm_discrp').contents().eq(2).text();
```

see [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2pk58ty4/)

contents() - Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes.

eq() - Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.