# how to get only the text of an element without getting the inline element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting text within element excluding decendants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487777/getting-text-within-element-excluding-decendants)

how to get only the text of an element without getting the inline element using jQuery?

I have the following problem:

```
<p><strong>Test 1</strong> this is test 1 results</p>
```

How do I capture only "this is test 1 results" into an array using jQuery? I attempted this but it's not working:

```
var TextResults = $("strong").parent("p").text();
var arrayTestResults = TextResults.split(" ");
```

Comment: Do you only want to capture the text in `p` and not the `strong`?

Comment: correct, only capture the text in the p element..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using contents.map() function (as suggested in the link provided by Felix Kling),
Something like this:

```
var result = $('p').contents().map(function() {
    if( this.nodeType === 3 ) {
        return this.data;
    }
   }).get().join('');
```

here is the full example, http://jsfiddle.net/z3Khs/3/

Comment: Your intention is good, but it is not necessary to repeat the answer. Instead, you should flag the question as duplicate of the one I linked to.