# Get text inside the label with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

From the following HTML, I want to get the text inside the `<label></label>` with jQuery but exclude the text inside the span in the label.

```
<label for="name">Name<span class="required">Required</span></label>
<input type="text" class="requiredField" name="name" />
```

I am trying following:

```
jQuery('.requiredField').each(function() {  
    var labelText = jQuery(this).prev().text();
}
```

It receives the text which is inside the span `.required` as well (ie. NameRequired), but I want to get only "Name". How can I exclude that? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting text within element excluding decendants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487777/getting-text-within-element-excluding-decendants)

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
jQuery('.requiredField').each(function() {  
    labelTextCopy = jQuery(this).prev().clone();
    copyChild = labelTextCopy.children();
    copyChild.remove();
    console.log(labelTextCopy.text());
})​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xRLg/5/

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way:
Create an `fn` that you can call again and again, rather than having to do `clone` and `remove` every where:

```
jQuery.fn.onlyText = function() {
    return this
            .clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text();
};

// And then your code

jQuery('.requiredField').each(function() {  
    var labelText = jQuery(this).prev().onlyText();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/OMS_/x7xPB/